# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: When I tried running ----> pydicom.dcmread(" <exact path of the dicom file> ")

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to do the following using Python:

```py
import pydicom
pydicom.dcmread(r"C:\Users\rubin\repos\pacs\pacs_script\20201020125804\deid\1.2.124.38368.160582868433113778804731394162156011275\1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.48.1220763049.1592440426.6416.9\1.2.392.200036.9116.2.1220763049.1592442586.11.1029100003.9.2767.dcm")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rubin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 847, in dcmread
    fp = open(fp, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\rubin\\repos\\pacs\\pacs_script\\20201020-125804\\deid\\1.2.124.38368.160582868433113778804731394162156011275\\1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.48.1220763049.1592440426.6416.9\\1.2.392.200036.9116.2.1220763049.1592442586.11.1029100003.9.2767.dcm'
```

I tried running as administrator, I am passing the exact file location in `dcmread` and I am working on a Windows machine. Please, help.

Comment: Can you check if you get the same error if you open that file on the Python command line (e.g. just `open(filename)`)? Or just try to open it in your app without pydicom.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen It is showing the same error when I did : open(<exact path of the file>)  in the command line

Comment: maybe the file is still open, so you get the errno13 permission denied

Comment: Hey, @y.y No the file is not opened. The only program I am running is the command line with this python code

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, the shorter path thing worked. Can you help me with handling the longer filenames if I want to use the actual path? Or is it the only solution to use the shorter path?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen, that `open(path)` failed with a `PermissionError` is definitely not because the filename is too long. It would fail with a `FileNotFoundError` in that case, and it's definitely not the case for the given path, which is only 238 characters long. The classic `MAX_PATH` (260) character limit supports null-terminated strings with up to 259 characters. Whatever moving/copying the file did to resolve the problem, it assuredly has nothing to do with the path length.

Comment: @ErykSun I am attaching the image of < os.stat(path) >. It says : os.stat_result(st_mode=16895, st_ino=1125899907192211, st_dev=4142110588, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0, st_atime=1603199479, st_mtime=1603199479, st_ctime=1603199479)

Comment: @ErykSun - you are right, I didn't remove the (double) delimiters from the string, so it is shorter than I thought. And I wasn't aware of the concrete error raised in that case - thanks. Will remove these comments to avoid confusion.

Comment: Apparently `path` is a directory, i.e. `st_mode == stat.S_IFDIR | 0o777` (16895). This is a strange case in Windows. The kernel returns a useful status code, `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY`, but the Windows API maps it to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (5), which in turn gets mapped to C `EACCES` (13). So Python, which only looks to C `errno` and sometimes Windows `GetLastError()` just raises a `PermissionError` when trying to open a directory as a file in Windows. In POSIX, `IsADirectoryError` is raised for this case.